# Integrate Angular App into existing Grails application?

Tags: angularjs, grails

We have an existing Grails 1.3.7 application that I cannot add plugins or additional dependencies to.  I would like to build a simple CRUD Angular application that the grails app would not need any knowledge of, other than rendering it to a GSP.  What would be the simplest and most straight forward way to integrate an angular app into an existing grails framework?  Would it be something as simple as using browserify and inlining the bundle.js, and adding an angular directive in the GSP?

Comment: What do you mean by Angular app? If by Angular you are referring to AngularJs, it is nothing but a javascript API, that you can add it to JS folder of you web app. You can add Angular controllers, services, directives, etc...

Comment: Is your Angular app communicates over JSON?